# Why is only the first prerequisite executed?

Tags: gnu-make

Here is the makefile.

```
.PHONY: all target1 target2 target
all: target1 target2
target1: NUM = 1
target2: NUM = 2
target1 target2: target
target:
    @echo "this is target ${NUM}"
```

And the output is:

```
this is target 1
```

Why is only the first prerequisite executed ?
I guess it's related to the variable.
Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Your Makefile says the following:

- all targets are phony (*i.e.* they don’t correspond to on-disk artifacts);
- `all` depends on `target1` and `target2`, and since it’s the first target, is the default target;
- `target1` sets `NUM` to 1 (using [target-specific variable assignments](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Target_002dspecific.html));
- `target2` sets `NUM` to 2;
- `target1` and `target2` both depend on `target`;
- `target` must be satisfied by running the given `echo` command.

Running `make` with these definitions will result in the following:

- `all` isn’t satisfied, since it’s phony, and needs `target1` and `target2`;
- `target1` isn’t satisfied, since it’s phony, and needs `target` (with `NUM` set to 1);
- `target` isn’t satisfied, since it’s phony, and has no prerequisites, so `make` runs the `echo` command;
- `target2` isn’t satisfied, since it’s phony, but `target` is satisfied, since it’s been processed already, so nothing happens.

You can’t use targets as functions, as you’re trying to do here; some Make implementations do support [functions](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Syntax-of-Functions.html), but you don’t need that:

```make
target1 target2:
    @echo "this is target ${NUM}"
```